# Using ignore_duplicate on non primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got table:

```
   ID (identity, PK), TaskNr, OfferNr
```

I want to do insert ignore statement but sadly it's not working on MSSQL, so there's a IGNORE_DUP switch. But I need to check duplicates using TaskNr column. Is there any chance to do that?

Edit:

Sample data:

```
ID (identity, PK), TaskNr, OfferNr
1                  BP1234   XAS
2                  BD123    JFRT
3                  1122AH   JDA33
4                  22345_a  MD_3
```

Trying to do:

```
insert ignore into Sample_table (TaskNr, OfferNr) values (BP1234, DFD,)
```

Should ignore that row and go to next value of insert statement. ID is autoincremented but unique value should be checked using TaskNr column.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Edited question, maybe now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support `insert ignore`.  That is MySQL functionality.

You can do what you want as:

```
insert ignore into Sample_table (TaskNr, OfferNr)
    select x.TaskNr, x.OfferNr
    from (select 'BP1234' as TaskNr, 'DFD' as OfferNr) x
    where not exists (select 1 
                      from Sample_Table st
                      where st.TaskNr = x.TaskNr and st.OfferNr = x.OfferNr
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks, that should do. I didn't worked with MSSQL for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can try two options:

- insert into ... where not exists ()
- t-sql merge statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)